# Scala/Play/Slick: select database name in DB.withSession

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick, play-slick

I'm using Slick in my Scala/Play project.

In the config I've defined my database URL like this:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost"
```

I have this simple method that runs a query. I need it to work on multiple databases(that cannot be defined in the conf), so I'm passing the database name as a parameter:

```
def getData(db: String): String = DB.withSession {
    sql"""SELECT myColumn FROM #$db.myTable LIMIT 1""".as[String].firstOption
}
```

This works just fine. But what I need is to convert the above example to this:

```
def getData(db: String): String = DB.withSession {
    sql"""SELECT myColumn FROM myTable LIMIT 1""".as[String].firstOption
}
```

Instead of just `DB.withSession` I need somehow to select the database name which is being passed with a param `db`. How can I do this?

**UPDATE:** I understand that something like `Database.forURL("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbName")` could work, but then it also requires user name, password, etc, which already exists for a default connection `DB`, so it doesn't make much sense entering all those settings again.